# Архитектура для сайтов с одинаковым функционалом

Tags: php, javascript, вёрстка, spa

Задача такая. Будет создаваться некоторое количество сайтов идентичных по функциональности, но с различным дизайном. Задаxf - максимально удешивить их разработку путем написания одного бэкэнда, работающего с любым из этих сайтов.

Сам пишу на java. Поэтому нет понимания вопроса. Пока вижу такие варинты:

1. Делаем API движок + SPA. Движок отвечает на запросы клиента JSON
   объектами, клиент рендерит сам для себя страницы и подставляет эти
   данные в них. Плюсы: Максильное отделение фронт от бэк. Движку
   вообще    все равно кому отвечать на запросы. Его пишем единожды для
   всех       сайтов. Минусы: Сложность=дороговизна разработки SPA
2. Делаем класический сайт. Рендрениг страниц на строне сервера. При
   разработке последующих сайтов переиспользуем часть классов
   движка(связь с БД и прочее).  Плюсы: Простота разработки. Минусы:
   Мне    не очень понятно насколько большую часть движка можно будет
   переиспользовать при изменении дизайна сайта, и какую переписывать
   заново. Если значительную, то, думаю, этот вариант лучший.
3. Делаем API движок + классический сайт и связываем их через
   движок-прослойку(его будем переписывать для каждого нового сайта),
   который будет рендерить страницы, а API-движок будет лазить в базу
   данных и заниматься шаблонными задачами. Минусы: Тут мне не ясно
   насколько сложно=дорого будет переделывать каждый раз
   движок-прослойку для рендеринга страниц.

Товарищи, какой вариант вам кажется привлекательнее на перспективу.

Comment: Всё зависит от конкретных задач, квалификации, минимальных требований к клиенту и серверу, возможного и невозможного развития в будущем итд итп, однозначно ответить будет очень трудно

Comment: @andreymal Вот некоторые исходные данные: Развитие\изменение функционала в будущем не требуется. Нагрузка на сайт не более 50тыс. посещений в сутки. Требуется максимальное удешевление разработки последующих сайтов. Еще раз повторюсь, функционал идентичен, меняться будет только дизайн. Предполагаемый стек технологий: PHP+MySQL+JS (Vue\React). В случаей с разработкой API-сервера собирался писать его на JAVA, но от идеи API пока решил отказать по причинам, указанным выше. Возможно и зря....

Answer (score 0):

ИМХО MVC (model-view-controller) вам в помощь. И любой из движков.
Бэк - пишется один.
А шаблоны страниц - могут быть какими угодно. И никаих прослоек.